# Error when not specify template arguments for alias template declared with default template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to allow user to generate their own Storage type, but I get lost with my last template metafunction.

**Base Storage Class :**

```
template < typename Data,
           typename P1,
           typename P2,
           typename P3 >
struct Storage : P1, P2, P3 {};
```

**Metafunction :**

```
template < template <typename,typename> typename Container,
           template <typename...> typename WrapperType,
           template <typename> typename Allocator = std::allocator >
struct MetaStorage {

  template < template <typename> typename P1,
             template <typename> typename P2,
             template <typename> typename P3 >
  struct With_Policies {

    template < typename ... Ts >
    struct With_Types {

      template < typename T = WrapperType<Ts...>,
                 typename Data = Container<T, Allocator<T>> >
      using type = Storage<Data,
                           P1<Data>,
                           P2<Data>,
                           P3<Data>>;
    };
  };
};
```

**Use Case :**

```
template <typename ... T > struct DefaultWrapper {};

template < typename T > struct Policie1 {};
template < typename T > struct Policie3 {};
template < typename T > struct Policie2 {};

struct C1 {};
struct C2 {};

using Sig = MetaStorage<std::vector, DefaultWrapper>::With_Policies<Policie1, Policie2, Policie3>::With_Types<C1, C2>::type;
```

**Error g++ 6.3:**

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: test.cpp:137:15: error: invalid  use of template-name ‘MetaStorage<std::vector,  DefaultWrapper>::With_Policies<Policie1, Policie2,  Policie3>::With_Types<C1, C2>::type’ without an argument list    using Sig = MetaStorage<std::vector,  DefaultWrapper>::With_Policies<Policie1, Policie2,  Policie3>::With_Types<C1, C2>::type;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ test.cpp:58:37: note: ‘template<class T, class Data> using type =  Storage<Data, Policie1<Data>, Policie2<Data>, Policie3<Data> >’  declared here
                             P3<Data>>;
                                      ^
```

Comment: Sorry I forget the Storage template! Well the main is empty anyway, just put the using inside.

Comment: Well, that changes quite a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` is declared as alias template, then template arguments are required here. Because the default arguments are declared, so just add `<>` for it, e.g.

```
using Sig = MetaStorage<std::vector, DefaultWrapper>::With_Policies<Policie1, Policie2, Policie3>::With_Types<C1, C2>::type<>;
//                                                                                                                         ~~
```

Comment: My bad, I was hoping the compiler doing this for me it seems... Thanks :)